# Cannot run php code, issue with angular routing

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I came across [this earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277925/executing-php-code-issue-caused-by-angular-routing) while searching for help on this issue, but there are no responses so I'm at a loss.

I am trying to submit a form and receive a php variable in return. I have no problems running the test code on its own, but when put into an angular app with routing enabled, I get no result. Clicking submit while on the routed page leads to nothing happening. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Here is my code:

HTML + PHP

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "IF GOOD :)";
} else {
    echo "ELSE BAD :(";
}?>
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/begin.html',
            controller: 'mainController',
            activePage: 'begin'
        });
});
```

Comment: Why you need to do that using php ?? you can do that thing using angular as your using it . use php only for data insert update delete. else handle everything using angular

Comment: I'm using php to make a call to a zillow api and return information on houses. Sorry that it wasn't clear in this, I just wanted to make the test work first before I moved on to anything else.

Comment: You can do that using angular too

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use angular to access the zillow api? Everything I've read mentions needing php or another server-side language to do it. If I could do it in angular alone that would save me so much hassle.

Comment: Give me the path of your api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to supply `<form>` with `action=""` attribute to make your code work.

From the [manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form):

> Since the role of forms in client-side Angular applications is
>   different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the
>   browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload
>   that sends the data to the server. Instead some javascript logic
>   should be triggered to handle the form submission in an
>   application-specific way.
>
> For this reason, Angular prevents the default action (form submission
>   to the server) unless the  element has an action attribute
>   specified.

However, Angular encourages you to use `ngSubmit` and ajax requests that cause no page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

Use php only for data insert/update/delete. else handle everything using angular

Try like this

**bengin.html**

```
<form >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" ng-click="submit()">
</form>
```

**mainController**

```
$scope.submit=function(){
  $http.post('msg.php', {submit:'hello word!'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  });
}
```

create file name msg.php

**msg.php**

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "IF GOOD :)";
} else {
    echo "ELSE BAD :(";
}?>
```